Executing a command is calling a function twice without reaching the breakpoint
I'm using Xamarin forms 5.0.0.2612.
My problem in a nutshell:
I want to delete an item in a collection. the collection is stored as a static property and while clicking the delete button, the item is already deleted at the moment the code stops on my breakpoint (which is responsible for the deletion).
I have a public static property called CurrentOrder of type "Order".
public static Order CurrentOrder { get; set; }
The "Order" class is a public class and is used to handle the orders (add, delete and modify..).

public int? SalesOrderId { get; set; } = null;

// items to order or already ordered
public List<OrderItem> OrderDetails { get; set; } = new List<OrderItem>();

// items to delete
public List<OrderItem> DeletedOrderDetails { get; set; } = new List<OrderItem>();


private IOrderManager _manager;


private readonly HttpService _httpsService;
private Order()
{           
    _httpsService = DependencyService.Resolve<HttpService>();

    // Create a new instance of the manager
    _manager = new OrderManagerFDM();
}

private Order(int salesOrderId, List<OrderItem> details) 
    : this()
{
    SalesOrderId = salesOrderId;
    OrderDetails = details;
}

public static Order Create(int salesOrderId, List<OrderItem> details)
    => new Order(salesOrderId, details);


public Result AddOrderItem(OrderItem order)
{
    return _manager.AddOrder(order, OrderDetails, DeletedOrderDetails);
}

public Result ModifyOrderItem(OrderItem order)
{
    return _manager.ModifyOrder(order, OrderDetails);
}

public Result RemoveOrderItem(OrderItem order)
{
    return _manager.RemoveOrder(order, OrderDetails, DeletedOrderDetails);
}


The IOrderManager is used to be able to switch the behavior depending on the configuration of the project. At the moment (for test) there is only one manager: OrderManagerFDM
public class OrderManagerFDM : IOrderManager
{
    // used to trace the commands
    private List<OrderItemCommand> _addAndDeleteCommands;

    public OrderManagerFDM()
    {
         _addAndDeleteCommands = new List<OrderItemCommand>();
    }   

       public Result RemoveOrder(OrderItem itemToDelete, List<OrderItem> orderDetails, List<OrderItem> deletedOrderDetails)
       {
           // Add the command
           _addAndDeleteCommands.Add(new OrderItemCommand(itemToDelete, OrderType.Remove));

           try
           {
               // Have a look in the current orderDetails collection to find the item to delete
               // And here, the itemToDelete is not found although it should be in the collection
               var existingOrdered = orderDetails.FirstOrDefault(x => x == itemToDelete);

               if (existingOrdered is null)
                   return Result.Failure("No item clould be found in orderDetails");

               // Check if item is already added to sales order
               if (existingOrdered.State == StateEnum.Update)
               {
                   orderDetails.Remove(itemToDelete);
                   
                   itemToDelete.IsOrdered = false;
                   deletedOrderDetails.Add(itemToDelete);
               }
               else
               {
                   if (existingOrdered.Quantity <= itemToDelete.Quantity)
                   {
                       orderDetails.Remove(itemToDelete);
                   }
                   else
                       existingOrdered.Quantity -= itemToDelete.Quantity;
               }
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               return Result.Failure(ex.ToString());
           }

           return Result.Success();
       }

}

Problem description:
In the view I have a command bound to the ViewModel
   DeleteCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteDelete());
This command execute the following code in a ViewModel:
        async Task ExecuteDelete()
        {
            // Breakpoint 1: All items in the collection
            OrderItem existingOrderDetail = Global.CurrentOrder
                                                     .OrderDetails
                                                     .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == _editOrderItemId);

            // Breakpoint 2 : the item to delete isn't anymore in the collection
            Global.CurrentOrder.RemoveOrderItem(existingOrderDetail);

            // Breakpoint 3: The item isn't in the deletedOrders collection because it couldn'd be   found in the _manager
            await ExecuteCancel();
        }

the first line, looks for the item I want to delete in the Global.CurrentOrder (the static property with the order) and the item is found.
Now, in the second line of code, calling the RemoveOrderItem from the static Global.Current and passing the item to delete. Now the item isn't anymore in the Global.CurrentOrder.OrderDetails collection before steping
Looking at the OrderManagerFDM instance of the current order, there is already an entry with delete the same item before I step into this code.
Breakpoint 1: The item to delete can be found in the collection

Breakpoint 2: The item isn't anymore in the collection
ItemToDelete doesn't exits anymore
Inside the Order on the Global.CurrentOrder, the custom state of the OrderItem "itemToDelete" is already marked as "Delete" and in the trace of the _manager I can see an entry with a delete.


And the the item to delete, who should now ne in the DeletedOrderDetails collection of Global.CurrentOrder is still empty.
May anyone have an idea where this could come from ?
To me it looks like something is running in different tasks, but I can't figure out how to avoid it.

I found the problem. It's the devexpress debug visualizer, evaluating the function before entering that is causing the problem.

Can I answer my own question?: Yes, you can, but not by commenting on the question....

I found the problem.
It's the DevExpress Debug Visualizer, evaluating the function before a breakpoint is hit
